# How do I apply an overflow to an overall div that has a div with text inside of it?

Tags: html, css

I have the following div setup with it's css.

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  border: solid;
}

.copy {
  white-space: nowrap; */
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class ="copy">
    Hello
    &nbsp
    <div class="name">
      G. Antetokounmponoustias
    </div>
    , let's go.
  </div>
<div>
```

What I want is to yield something that looks like "Hello G. Antetokounmponoust...", and not "Hello G. Antetok..., let's go." The reason is that I need to truncate the name or the entirety of the sentence basics on media viewport.

Is this possible using divs?

I was able to successfully do this with a span inside of the div and an `inline-block` display, but the alignment was off, so I switched to a div. The truncation works, it just doesn't show an ellipsis now for the overflow.

Comment: remove the inner div 
that has the class="name"

Answer (score 0):

without the div

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  border: solid;
}

.copy {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class ="copy">
    Hello
    &nbsp
      G. Antetokounmponoustias
    , let's go.
  </div>
<div>
```

with div

```css
.container {
  border: solid;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.copy {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div style="min-width: 0; display: inline-flex;">
    Hello
    &nbsp
    <div class="copy">
      G. Antetokounmponoustias
    </div>
    , let's go.
    </div>
  <div>
```

Comment: I need the inner div. Is this the only way?

Comment: I have added new answer.